# How to avoid type mismatches in lookup?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a linear interpolation in Haskell:

```
linear_interpolation:: [(Double, Double)] -> Double -> Maybe Double
linear_interpolation list x
    | x1 /= Nothing && x2 /= Nothing && y1 /= Nothing && y2 /= Nothing
      = Just (y1+ (y2-y1)*(x - x1)/(x2 - x1))
    | otherwise = Nothing
      where
        x2 = find (> x) (x_list list)
        x1 = max_elem $ filter (< x) (x_list list)
        y1 = lookup x1 list
        y2 = lookup x2 list
```

But I get this error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Double’ with ‘Maybe Double’
      Expected: [(Maybe Double, Double)]
        Actual: [(Double, Double)]
    • In the second argument of ‘lookup’, namely ‘list’
      In the expression: lookup x2 list
      In an equation for ‘y2’: y2 = lookup x2 list
   |
29 |         y2 = lookup x2 list
   |                        ^^^^
```

I don't really understand what's going on, because lookup type is like that:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

P.S

The same problem for y1, x1, x2

Answer (score 2):

Testing `x1 /= Nothing` doesn't change the type of `x1`, which is still `Maybe Double`, so we can't perform arithmetic operations on `x1`.

For this reason, testing `x1 /= Nothing`, `isNothing x1`, or `isJust x1` is most likely to be the wrong thing to do. Most often what we really need to use is *pattern matching*:

```
linear_interpolation
   :: [(Double, Double)] -> Double -> Maybe Double
linear_interpolation list x = let
   x2 = find (> x) (x_list list)
   x1 = max_elem $ filter (< x) (x_list list)
   in case (x1, x2) of
      (Just x1', Just x2') -> let
         y1 = lookup x1' list
         y2 = lookup x2' list
         in case (y1, y2) of
            (Just y1', Just y2') ->
               Just (y1' + (y2' - y1')*(x - x1')/(x2' - x1'))
            -> Nothing
      _ -> Nothing
```

Here, `x1',x2',y1',y2'` will have the wanted type `Double`.

The nested `let` and `case` is not so readable. In this case, it's simpler if we exploit the `Maybe` monad and use `do` notation.

```
linear_interpolation
   :: [(Double, Double)] -> Double -> Maybe Double
linear_interpolation list x = do
   x2 <- find (> x) (x_list list)
   x1 <- max_elem $ filter (< x) (x_list list)
   y1 <- lookup x1 list
   y2 <- lookup x2 list
   Just (y1 + (y2 - y1)*(x - x1)/(x2 - x1))
```

Here, using `<-`, we make `x1,x2,y1,y2 :: Double` removing the `Maybe` from the type. The `Nothing` case is automatically dealt with, which makes it rather convenient.

Comment: ```
y1 = lookup x1 list
y2 = lookup x2 list
```
Here the problem persists

Comment: @student422 Right, I missed that. I'll fix it.